# Dropdown custom table

Tags: magento-1.9, column, entities, ce-1.9.2.1

I know that it is possible to create dropdowns using the EAV strategy used in Magento, yet I was not able find any information over creating a dropdown in an entity without using EAV.

Does someone have an example somwhere, either online or in the core magento code?

I am working on magento ce 1.9.2.1
Thanks

Comment: Why not use EAV? That makes life so much easier when you have to work and process your values later on.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl: Is that true? So its just normal to always use the EAV model, no matter which table?

Comment: For categories, products, customers & customer addresses which use the EAV structure: yes.

Comment: Ok, and what if I am building my own module with a new table?

Comment: I see. I was assuming you are going to create a product or customer attribute, then EAV makes sense. If your are building your own module, the database architecture is up to you.

Comment: Do you want to create a dropdown for the frontend or the backend (system configuration)?